# Unbalanced Parenthesis Error with re.Compile

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parentheses

I am porting an older Python code to Python 3. The code worked in Python 2.7. The following line is creating an unbalanced parenthesis error:

```
pp = re.compile('\\\([^\\<\/td\ *\>\([^\<]*)\<\/td\ *\>\[^\<]*\<\/td\ *\>\([^\<]*)\<\/td\ *\>\([^\<]*)\<\/td\ *\>\([^\<]*)\<\/td\ *\>\<\/tr\ *\>')
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated how to break this down and figure it out.

Comment: Holy too many backslashes, batman! Use a `r''` raw string literal to cut back on all of those. `/` does not need to be escaped.

Comment: And the code does *not* work on Python 2.7 for me.

Comment: Oh, and perhaps you wanted to use a HTML parser instead? I suspect your code will be a lot simpler with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, did you mean WATman? :P Sorry for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is almost unreadable, and most of the `\` backslashes are actually meaningless. Those that do have meaning though are the `\[`, `\(` and `\)` combinations, most of which look like they should not be there *at all*.

For example. the part `\[^\<]` is broken, as the escaped `\[` makes the `]` bracket unbalanced.

Removing all the backslashes makes the pattern compile:

```
>>> re.compile('([^</td *>([^<]*)</td *>[^<]*</td *>([^<]*)</td *>([^<]*)</td *>([^<]*)</td *></tr *>')
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f8c61c76d50>
```

Not that the pattern makes any more sense in that case, as there is a `[^` there at the start signifying a opening character class, but the characters that follow it suggest that that was not the intent there, the `\[` we saw early might be part of that class then but then you'd be matching anything that is not in the set `{'<', '/', 't', 'd', ' ', '*', '(', '[', '^', '<'}`, which is probably not what you wanted either.

In short, the whole expression is severely broken, and won't work in the current form in any Python version.

It also looks like you are trying to parse HTML with a regular expression. That is not going to work very well. Use a proper HTML parser instead, BeautifulSoup for example would make the task of extracting table cell data much simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. You are correct. The new code does compile. For clarification, this is an old code I inherited and was told it ran OK. My mistake: I should have run it myself first to verify. I actually have 4 lines of this type of code. I will try to fix it myself along the lines you suggested. As an aside, why would anyone have coded this this way? I will also check out BeautifulSoup. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like someone copied and pasted regular expressions from somewhere without understanding what it does; perhaps even from something that was meant for Perl or JavaScript instead. I cannot imagine anyone actually writing that and understanding what they were doing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will try it out and work on it. I will also look at BeautifulSoup. Once again, thank you very much.